# How to add custom message with alignment in Welcome message of MSI installer using wix

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3

I used this line in wxl file to add custom message but still not able to align the version number properly

```
  <String Id="WelcomeDlgDescription" Overridable="yes">The Setup Wizard will install [ProductName] on your computer. Click Next to continue or Cancel to exit the Setup Wizard.&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;{\WixUI_Font_Title}Version - [ProductVersion]</String>
```

**I want the results to be like this**

[image]

Also, I am not able to change the fonts.

**Updated**

I am able to achieve this. Version left hanging in the middle and not going at the end,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Limitation***: It looks like you can only have one style per string. I am not sure, but it says in the documentation that you have to refer to the style at the beginning of the string:

```
<TextStyle Id="Test" FaceName="Arial" Blue="255" Size="12" Strike="yes" />

<..>

<String Id="WelcomeDlgDescription">{\Test}Version - [ProductVersion]</String>
```

- [Adding Controls and Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/adding-controls-and-text)
- [ICE31 - validation suite checking Strings and fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/ice31) (see Examples)

> ***Customizing WiX Dialogs***: You might need to change the whole dialog to add two fields so you can put the version number in its own
>   text box featuring its own style. Doing so is a little involved, and I have a description of
>   it here: [**Customizing WiX Dialogs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654935/changing-text-color-to-wix-dialogs/52674815#52674815). Please have a quick read. It also describes how to change font color and style.

***Update***: Nice little sample for how you can insert a custom dialog: [Wix UpgradeVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150902/wix-upgradeversion).

Comment: My first problem is that I am not able to append version at the end of Welcome string. You can see in my code that I have entered a new line using '&#13;&#10'. But still, the version is left hanging in the middle.

Comment: As I posted above, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150902/wix-upgradeversion) will show you how you can create your own GUI sequence by referring to existing dialog sets (such as Mondo) and then injecting your own dialog defined in its own wxs file (the UI section). You do this injetion by adjusting the events on the controls involved in dialogs in the dialog set (you override the original events). The actual modified dialog of yours would feature a separate field for your version where you apply the style as the first entry in the string, as explained above.

Comment: [Maybe see Helge Klein's real world sample](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/) for dialog changes (**`ServerDlg.wxs`**, **`WixUI_HK.wxs`**, **`LicenseAgreementDlg_HK.wxs`**) and many other nice features. Remember styling such as **``{\Test}``** must be first in the string. First character.