# Wix MSI installer is not removing previous version from "Add/Remove Applications" when updating the application

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have created a new installer with a new version and Product ID with no errors but when it is installed, the current version remains installed as well as the updated version. I have been using this for a while to install and update my application on different machines but only recently has it started to not delete the old version completely. I have updated the .wxs file as follows:

```
1. Changed <Product Id="{F9030CA1-39AD-46BD-B2E2-3DBE02A8845B}".
2. Updated the new version number.
```

I have not updated the Upgrade Code. 
I have created multiple versions of the installer to see if the problem persist and it seems as it does. I have also updated the Wix extension to visual studio (Votive2019) but no luck.
 Not sure if there is a fault with my code or if this is a bug. I am not even sure what the cause of this problem is.

Below is a snippet of my code from the package section:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="{F9030CA1-39AD-46BD-B2E2-3DBE02A8845B}" Codepage="1252" Language="1033" Manufacturer="Mi-Plan" Name="FD to Excel" UpgradeCode="{17469B04-7B24-455E-BCB8-CD7AEA97CDCD}" Version="10.0.560">
        <Package Compressed="yes" Description="10.0.560.0" InstallerVersion="200" Languages="1033" Manufacturer="Jwayela Software" Platform="x86" />
```

Below is a snippet of my code from the upgrade section:

```html
  <Upgrade Id="{A39F99F9-069F-4356-AA6A-5BBBC6DADB29}">
            <UpgradeVersion Maximum="10.0.560" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" />
            <UpgradeVersion Minimum="10.0.560" Property="NEWERPRODUCTFOUND" OnlyDetect="yes" IncludeMinimum="yes" />
        </Upgrade>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tRQNQcjIIavs737ml6ZxHvskunZ4og23) to get full file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Type Mismatch Error***: It looks like there is a mismatch between the **`Upgrade element's "Id" value`** and the **`Upgrade Code`** you have specified in the **`Product element`**? That would explain why the major upgrade doesn't work, but not why it has worked so far?

---

***Major Upgrade Element***: Would recommend you use the simplified major upgrade element if you don't need fine grained control in the Upgrade table for something special. I just wrote an answer for this a few hours ago: [Unable to remove previous versions of MSI. Multiple entry's show up in control panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281893/unable-to-remove-previous-versions-of-msi-multiple-entrys-show-up-in-control-p/). Magixal **`MajorUpgrade element`** - this single, simple line does all the work for you:

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
```

---

***Define***: Another thing is that **`Defines`** can be used to set values that are to be used in different places in the source and need to match exactly all the time:

```
<?define MyProductVersion = "31.00.0000" ?>
<?define MyProductCode = "PUT-GUID-HERE" ?>
<?define MyUpgradeCode = "PUT-GUID-HERE" ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Product Id="$(var.MyProductCode)" Codepage="1252" Language="1033" Manufacturer="Corp"
           Name="Bla" UpgradeCode="$(var.MyUpgradeCode)" Version="$(var.MyProductVersion)">

   <...>

   <!-- Major upgrade -->
    <Upgrade Id="$(var.MyUpgradeCode)">

      <!-- Downgrade Protection -->
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.MyProductVersion)" OnlyDetect="yes" 
                      IncludeMinimum="yes" Property="DOWNGRADE_DETECTED"  />

      <!-- Major Upgrade Configuration -->
      <UpgradeVersion IncludeMinimum="no" Maximum="$(var.MyProductVersion)" 
                      IncludeMaximum="no" MigrateFeatures="yes" Property="UPGRADE_DETECTED" />
    </Upgrade>

</Wix>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The product Upgrade Product Id and Upgrade Product Code were not the same and that was the issue. I will definitely give the Major Upgrade Element a shot and will implement the definitions to make life much easier for future upgrades.